# Identityserver 4 introspection showing token status as active after sign-out

Tags: identityserver4, access-token

After I logout from identity server, I tried to access introspect using postman but I am getting status as active but after 5min only getting active status as false

https://localhost:5000/connect/introspect

I also tried to access API using the same token but I am getting unauthorize error (401) as expected. Please note that in API I have added the setting **ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),**

How to set introspect to return the correct result after token expires without adding the extra sync time.